# How to use two mat-pagination in a single page to get different page index

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives, angular-material-5

I am facing an issue when using a mat-pagination for my angular 5 applications where I have two tables with pagination. For one table the pagination is working fine. But when there is change in the second pagination i.e. When I add a some comments to the table the `pageindex` of the first table pagination is getting changed.

How to stop the first pagination `pageindex` value from changing when I update the second?

I have also tried using `viewchildren` instead of `viewchild` but I am not able to get the `pageindex`.

Comment: A minimal, working example of your code would be most helpful in diagnosing the problem. 

stackblitz.com is a good way to do that

Comment: We have found the solution for this issue thanks for your time.